# If I run a minikube instance on ubuntu do I need a VM like virtualbox?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, minikube

If I run a minikube instance on ubuntu do I need a VM like virtualbox?

If I run `minikube start` it complains that I need to install a VM, seems weird to have to do that on linux tho.

Comment: what exactly does it say?

Comment: it says I need to install a VM, I installed virtualbox, so I lost the error message, but just curious, I read that you don't need to install a VM last week

Comment: Ahhh, _minikube_. Of course. Thought you're talking about microk8s. Try that one instead.

Comment: thanks for the microk8s tip, I got that working

Answer (score 2):

While it is possible to run without a VM via `--vm-driver=none` it really isn't recommended outside of ephemeral CI instances. Minikube expects to be able to take over the system pretty fully to do its thang. I would recommend checking out one of the other tools to manage a local environment like microk8s (available as a Snap too), Kind, or possibly k3s.

Comment: nah `minikube start --drive=none` won't launch anything it just says:  `Error: unknown flag: --driver
Usage:
  minikube start [flags]`

Comment: Sorry, that should probably be `--vm-driver`. It's the standard interface for setting which VM driver to use, the key is the semi-undocumented `none` driver which means "just run everything locally". Again, this is very much not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

**Just use [microk8s](https://microk8s.io/) instead**

https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/install-a-local-kubernetes-with-microk8s#4

that's what you need